# MYSQL foreign key constraint check in transaction?

Tags: mysql

I have following error while executing following transaction.
*Error : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crowdsource`.`posts_category`, CONSTRAINT `FK_posts_pcategory` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`post_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)*

Transaction:

**start transaction;
select @id := max(post_id) from `posts`;
set @id = @id+1;
INSERT INTO `posts`(`post_id`,`content`, `url`, `post_time`) VALUES (@id,'hello','',now());
SELECT * from posts;
INSERT INTO `posts_category`(`post_id`, `category_id`) VALUES (@id,1001),(@id,1002);
commit;**

My database schema has FK between `posts` and `posts_category` tables ('post_id')

Do I need to keep SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; before inserting into post_category table?

Comment: dang that edit made it worse

Answer (score 1):

From the Manual, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) too. The use of `auto_increment` columns  is highly encouraged unless you want to really roll the dice.
Meaning, this: `select @id := max(post_id) ...` is un-safe. It is a manual, error-prone, programmer incrementation. In theory, many users could have just run that at the same time, now we all have the same id.

---

Instead, use

```
SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

... after an insert, which safely gets the `id` in table inserts (presumably) that are coming up next.

---

As for your FK problem, do not update or insert a row that violates the referential integrity that you so wisely put there in the first place.

Other comment: why in the middle of a transaction, meant to be snappy fast, are you doing a `select * from posts` ? How is that even useful?

Comment: sorry, that's a mistake(Select * from posts)

Comment: that's the best I got for ya, in case you were waiting on me. Yep, that's it